# Como criar uma regra de negócio pelo JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

Eu preciso implementar uma regra de negócio que garanta que o mesmo funcionário representada pela tabela **Employee** não possa ser adicionado mais de uma vez ao mesmo projeto representada pela tabela **Project**. Deixar eu dar um exemplo;

Vamos supor que temos os seguintes registros

```
EMPLOYEE (table)
ID  NAME   
1   Bob     
2   Sarah 

PROJECT (table)
ID  NAME
1   GIS
2   SIG
```

O sistema identifica as seguintes ações ao salvar um registro

```
EMP_PROJ (table)
EMP_ID  PROJ_ID
1        1
1        2
2        1
```

A regra de negócio é quando existir uma ação de salvar por exemplo abaixo ele gere um erro de exceção;

```
EMP_PROJ (table)
EMP_ID  PROJ_ID
1         3
```

Eu poder realizar a exceção através do mapeamento do JPA, veja o mapeamento;

Project

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 300)
    private String name;
```

Emp_Proj

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp_proj")
public class Emp_Proj {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Long emp_id;
    private Long proj_id;
```

Employee

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 300)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal salary;


    @Size(min = 2, message = "Selecione pelo menos dois projetos")
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Emp_Proj", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id")
                , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "proj_id"))
```

O que aconteceu foi que ao tentar inserir um funcionário em três projeto o sistema permitiu e não gerou nenhuma exceção apesar de ter criando uma validação com **Size**.

Como faço para resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu repositório, se estiver usando Spring data JPA vc pode fazer o seguinte:

```
    public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Emp_Proj, Long> {
       @Query("SELECT COUNT(e) FROM Emp_Proj e WHERE e.emp_id=:id")
       Long numProjetosFuncionarios(@Param("id") Long id);
    }
```

Aí com esse retorno vc trata sua regra de negócio, por exemplo se o resultado for maior que 2, lança a exception e não.